# HTML JQuery Get Element Width Inside of iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Have this iframe on page:

```
<iframe name="fileFrame" id="fileFrame" class="fileFrame" style="display:none;" src="http://example.com" height="50%" width="50%"></iframe>
```

The iframe has an element inside of it pulled from other website:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="display:block; width: 18%;"></div>
```

How can I get the main page to pull the progress bars width?

Trying to track this to get main page to update when the progress bar is finished loading (100%) in the iframe.

Tried this and didn't work:

```
var mydivw = $("#fileFrame").contents().find(".progress-bar").width();
alert(mydivw);
```

Comment: Is this a cross origin iframe? or is it same domain as page? If it's not you can't access it due to *same origin policy*

Comment: Cross origin, the iframe is loading a file hosting site.

Comment: Then you can not get inside it

Comment: Is there anyway to load form a file hosting site and update the main page when its done? Sorry for my ignorance on this subject...

Comment: Too many unknowns to answer that easily. Depends on file type...what you are trying to do, file hosting restrictions .....etc. Depending on what you are trying to do might also be able to do it on your server with a proxy script or might be as simple as using some ajax

Comment: Ah, Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$("#fileFrame").contents().find(".progress-bar").width()
```

You can put it on load

Like this

```
$("#fileFrame").on("load",function(){

  var width=$(this).contents().find(".progress-bar").width()

})
```

Comment: Updated original post, I tried that, I think? What am I doing wrong?